# Data structure for non overlapping ranges of integers?

Tags: data-structures, functional-programming

I remember learning a data structure that stored a set of integers as ranges in a tree, but it's been 10 years and I can't remember the name of the data structure, and I'm a bit fuzzy on the details. If it helps, it's a functional data structure that was taught at CMU, I believe in 15-212 (Principles of Programming) in 2002.

Basically, I want to store a set of integers, most of which are consecutive. I want to be able to query for set membership efficiently, add a range of integers efficiently, and remove a range of integers efficiently. In particular, I **don't** care to preserve what the original ranges are. It's better if adjacent ranges are coalesced into a single larger range.

A naive implementation would be to simply use a generic set data structure such as a HashSet or TreeSet, and add all integers in a range when adding a range, or remove all integers in a range when removing a range. But of course, that would waste a lot of memory in addition to making add and remove slow.

I'm thinking of a purely functional data structure, but for my current use I don't need it to be. IIRC, lookup, insertion, and deletion were all O(log N), where N was the number of ranges in the set.

So, can you tell me the name of the data structure I'm trying to remember, or a suitable alternative?

Comment: Well, there are interval trees (see Wikipedia), but these don't coalesce ranges.

Comment: I'm not into functional programming, but it sounds like you need a self-balanced search tree of intervals.

Comment: How large a set of integers? How many? What's their range, etc?

Comment: Lasse: int64, and trillions (US) or billions (for everyone else)  of integers consisting of at most a few hundred ranges, at least half of which will be adjacent to another.

Comment: @aij: Do you talk about [segment trees](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?d1=tutorials&d2=lowestCommonAncestor&module=Static#Segment_Trees)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the old homework and the data structure I had in mind were [Discrete Interval Encoding Trees](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/diet/) or diets for short. They are described in detail in [Diets for Fat Sets](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/papers/Diet_JFP98.pdf), Martin Erwig. Journal of Functional Programming, Vol. 8, No. 6, 627-632, 1998. It is basically a tree of intervals with the invariant that all of the intervals are non-overlapping and non-touching. There is a Haskell implementation in [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diet). I was hoping there would be an existing implementation for Scala, but I'm not seeing any.

The homework also included another data structure they called a Recursive Interval-Occluding Tree (RIOT), which rather than keeping only an interval at each node keeps an interval and another (possibly empty) RIOT of things removed from the interval. The assignment included benchmarks showing it did better than diets for random insertions and deletions. AFAICT it is simply something the TAs made up and never published as it no longer seems to exist anywhere on the Internets, at least not under that name.

Answer (score 3):

You probably are looking for segment trees. This might be helpful: http://www.topcoder.com/tc?d1=tutorials&d2=lowestCommonAncestor&module=Static

You can also use binary search trees for the same, for which each node will have two data fields: min_val and max_val.

During insertion algorithm, you just need to call another merging operation to check if the left-child,parent,right-child create a sequence, so as to club them into a single node. This will take O(log n) time.

Other operations like deletion and look-up will take O(log n) time as usual, but special measures need to be taken while deletion.

Comment: Segment trees are similar (and I came a cross them a lot in my search due to keywords being the same) but as you point out insertion and deletion are wrong/different since segment trees specifically do store overlapping intervals separately and let you query for the original intervals.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.. Using binary search trees for this purpose, I wanted you to create a different algorithm for this purpose, however, segment trees serve similar purpose so it was replaced.

Comment: @Sanjay, nice answer but that link isn't loading for me. This article addresses the same data structure: http://letuskode.blogspot.in/2013/01/segtrees.html